# Grease pencil conversion

Tags: grease-pencil

I can't convert GP into mesh or curve.

There are tools options to convert but nothing happens.

I was following old tutorial but now is something different.

Comment: Assuming you use standard conversion (no BSurfaces) - are you sure it wasn't actually converted ? Grease Pencil strokes remain visible after conversion and overlay the curve which is thin, so uncheck visiblity for GP layer and see in Outliner / 3D view if curve appeared.

Comment: I can't select curve with right click so I think it's not there or it's not created .

Comment: It still isn't clear.. Can you [make a short gif](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) of the process ? In the animation please include viewport with the Toolshelf opened, Outliner and no more than 1-2 objects in the scene. You could also [upload the file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) before the conversion.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out. I have been in edit mode so conversion was greyed out. When I switched in object mode, I could make conversion.